# Installing PostFix on Ubuntu (Lucid Lynx) from terminal window from script using apt-get postfix: no options to select

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04, postfix

Actually I'm using

> sudo apt-get install bzr bzr-builddeb equivs

(though sudo apt-get install postfix seems to be doing the same thing) from the terminal windows, [As per the iFolder instructions for installing Simias](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/iFolderInstall), but postfix is a dependency (I guess).  Someone else seemed to have the [same problem](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/176303-solved-how-install-postfix-ununtu-10-10-a.html) as I, but there was no resolution of the issue there.

What is happening is that a configuration screen opens up, with the configuration options, but I can't seem to select anything (and there is no cancel option).

Any idea what is going wrong?  How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried hitting the tab key to see if a selector appears? Or up and down arrow keys?

Comment: Up and down arrows were just sliding me through the text, but not giving me anything to select (not even "Ok").  I'll try tab and get back to you here.

Comment: Okay, I'm dumb (small comfort, apparently I'm not the only one).  Tab did the trick.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: This happened to me (no cursor initially, and when I hit tab it would only highlight "ok"), and I think it was because the terminal window was too small to display everything, so hitting arrow keys would just scroll it. I exited the session and tried again fullscreen, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the tab key. See if the selector appears.